# Как сделать вход без подключения к БД?

Tags: html, php

Я написал вот такую форму в *index.php*:

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="login" /><br />
 <input type="password" name="pass" /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="кнопка" />
</form>
```

и вот такой код в *login.php*:

```
<?php if ($_POST['pass']=="123" and $_POST['login']=="admin") {
..если пасс робит
} else {
..если пасс неверен
}  ?>
```

Но мне выдает какую-то ошибку. Почему? Напишите, что неправильно.

Comment: какуя ошибку ?

Comment: Я откуда знаю, обновляюсь и пишет, что в папке логин и индекс пхп ошибки(

Comment: Правильно будет так:

        <?php if (($_POST['pass']=="123")&&($_POST['login']=="admin"))

Comment: Где и что именно пишет?

Comment: Вот что пишет, хотя я заменил!

>Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in D:\home\test1.ru\www\login.php on line 2

Comment: Что у вас на второй строке login.php и что вы заменили?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял то проблема решается так

```
<?php
if ($_POST['pass']=="123" and $_POST['login']=="admin") {
    echo '..если пасс робит';
} else {
    echo '..если пасс неверен';
}  
?>
```

Comment: +1 за `echo` отключился)

Comment: а как сделать если мне надо при нажатии на кнопку перекидывало на блог?

Comment: что надо поставить в заместо echo?

Comment: Не проще сначала почитать азы? А затем уж ставить задачи?

Answer (score 7):

Ув. [[@Саша Осипов](/users/8079/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/8079/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2)  если будете писать вот так

> ..если пасс робит

в php, то ошибки не закончатся!

в php комментарии пишутся:

```
//вот так
#вот так
/*вот так*/
```

А `syntax error, unexpected '.'` это первая точка в вашем `->` *..если пасс робит*

Comment: А я думал, это просто замена реального кода для вопроса...

Comment: та ото ж... даже подумать не мого что там именно "..если пасс робит"

Comment: *мда.весело ребята...*)

Comment: дак это я просто там оставил, а так у себя заменил!